# permalink adding unwanted question mark

Tags: wordpress

All of a sudden, my permalink structure %postname% is not working anymore. It adds an unwanted question mark.
Example: https://www.bulkdeal.in/product-category/quirky-collection/?v=fab0a655ee1e

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: That question mark is necessary for the querystring. Do you mean the *querystring* is unwanted?

Comment: Please give us some more detail about what you've tried, what code changes you have made recently or anything else that might be affecting the permalinks. Be as detailed as possible!

Comment: @FluffyKitten Yes questing is unwanted

Comment: @koosa I had added (custom fee-based cart subtotal) code in the last few days and added some products to my website.

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce => Setting => General => Default customer location - Remove (Geolocat with page caching support) Choose Other Option in this field [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96St4.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1GBf.png)